# tic tac toe game DeclareWinner (c++)

Tags: c++

i have made my first tic tac toe game and i am i little stuck.
my question:

- how can i let a player win
- how to make it so you can't enter an number on the same place twice

here is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

void TTTBoard();
void players();
char playerX();
char playerO();
void boardWriterX(char, char);
void boardWriterO(char, char);
std::string row = "# 1 #       #       #       #";
std::string row2 = "# 2 #       #       #       #";
std::string row3 = "# 3 #       #       #       #";
bool refresh = false;
int playerTimer = 1;

int main()
{
    TTTBoard();
    return 0;
}
void TTTBoard()
{   

    do{ 
        std::cout << "#############################" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "#       1       2       3   #" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "#   #########################" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "#   #       #       #       #" << std::endl;
        std::cout << row << std::endl;
        std::cout << "#   #       #       #       #" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "#   #########################" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "#   #       #       #       #" << std::endl;
        std::cout << row2 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "#   #       #       #       #" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "#   #########################" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "#   #       #       #       #" << std::endl;
        std::cout << row3 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "#   #       #       #       #" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "#############################" << std::endl;
        refresh = false;
        } while (refresh);
    players();

}
void players()
{

    if (playerTimer % 2 == 0) 
    {
        std::cout << "its player[O] turn" << std::endl;
        std::cout << playerTimer << std::endl;
        playerTimer++;
        playerX();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "its player[X] turn" << std::endl;
        std::cout << playerTimer << std::endl;
        playerTimer++;
        playerO();
    }
}
char playerX()
{
    char X, Y;
    std::cout << "Give the coordinates of you move" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "X as: ";
    std::cin >> X;
    std::cout << "Y as: ";
    std::cin >> Y;
    boardWriterX(X, Y);
    return X, Y;
}
char playerO()
{
    char X, Y;
    std::cout << "Give the coordinates of you move" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "X as: ";
    std::cin >> X; 
    std::cout << "Y as: ";
    std::cin >> Y;
    boardWriterO(X, Y);
    return X, Y;
}
void boardWriterX(char X, char Y)
{
    if (X == '1')
    {
        if (Y == '1')
        {
            row.replace(8, 1, "O");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
        else if (Y == '2')
        {
            row.replace(16, 1, "O");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
        else if (Y == '3')
        {
            row.replace(24, 1, "O");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
    }
    else if (X == '2')
    {
        if (Y == '1')
        {
            row2.replace(8, 1, "O");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
        else if (Y == '2')
        {
            row2.replace(16, 1, "O");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
        else if (Y == '3')
        {
            row2.replace(24, 1, "O");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
    }
    else if (X == '3')
    {
        if (Y == '1')
        {
            row3.replace(8, 1, "O");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
        else if (Y == '2')
        {
            row3.replace(16, 1, "O");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
        else if (Y == '3')
        {
            row3.replace(24, 1, "O");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
    }
}
void boardWriterO(char X, char Y)
{
    if (X == '1')
    {
        if (Y == '1')
        {
            row.replace(8, 1, "X");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
        else if (Y == '2')
        {
            row.replace(16, 1, "X");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
        else if (Y == '3')
        {
            row.replace(24, 1, "X");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
    }
    else if (X == '2')
    {
        if (Y == '1')
        {
            row2.replace(8, 1, "X");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
        else if (Y == '2')
        {
            row2.replace(16, 1, "X");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
        else if (Y == '3')
        {
            row2.replace(24, 1, "X");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
    }
    else if (X == '3')
    {
        if (Y == '1')
        {
            row3.replace(8, 1, "X");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
        else if (Y == '2')
        {
            row3.replace(16, 1, "X");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
        else if (Y == '3')
        {
            row3.replace(24, 1, "X");
            refresh = true;
            TTTBoard();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you could use a *matrix*, also known as a "2d array", or array of arrays as it really is. This could be as simple as `char board[3][3]`, where an empty element (e.g. space or the `'\0'` character, or whatever you want) could mark an empty spot in the board, and then you have `'X'` or `'O'` to mark the players moves.

Using a matrix like that it's very easy to see if a player can place his or her mark on a specific position. It's also very easy to check for three in a row to see if there is a winner, and also who is the winner.